# How to prove two statements given axioms

Tags: logic, proof-writing, quantifiers, natural-deduction

I have no idea what to do or what kind of proof to use for this. Please help.

> Given the following axioms:
>
> a.∀x (P(x)→ R(x))
>
> b.Ǝx (¬R(x)∧ Q(x))
>
> Prove: Ǝx (Q(x)∧ ¬P(x)).
>
> Show the rules of inference (and prior steps) used at each step:

This is what I have tried but I don't think this is correct

$\begin{array}{ll}\text{Assume}&\exists x~(\lnot R(x)\land Q(x))\\
\text{since}&\exists x~\lnot R(x)\\
&        \lnot R(x)\\
\text{because}& P(x) \to R(x)\\
\text{but}& \forall x~ (P(x) \to R(x))\\
\text{this is a contradiction so}& \exists x~(\lnot R(x)\land Q(x))\text{ is false}
\end{array}$

Comment: So, it would help us (who might be interested in answering), if you add what you've tried, where you are stuck, identifying the rules of inference that are available to you, etc. AND add that within your question post, as an edit to the current post, no only in comments.

Comment: @amWhy I just updated this

Comment: I truly do not understand what $x$ is when you say $\exists x \lnot R\;\;x\lnot R $, nor can I follow your reasoning.  You never even mention how $Q(x),\;P(x)$ relate, let alone what is required to prove $\exists x (Q(x) \land \lnot P(x)$.  You need to begin your proof with assumption (a), next line assumption (b),  both of which are taken as  given and then apply existential instantiation, then universal instantiation, then manipulate, and then then re-express via   existential generalization. to conclude what you are asked to prove.

Comment: @amWhy I do not know how to do that. So that's why I am here. I know that what I had was wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: another option is to include both "axioms (premises)", one line each.  And on the third line, assume $\lnot\Big(Ǝx Q(x)∧ ¬P(x) \Big) \equiv \forall x \big(\lnot (Q(x) \land \lnot P(x)\big) \equiv \forall x \big(\lnot Q(x) \lor P(x)\big)$.  (DeMorgan's at the end).  If you can find a way to show that this third line, an assumption (for the sake of contradiction) contradicts any one of the two axioms (given premises), you will have proven what you are asked to do.

Comment: @GrahamKemp, your edit made no more sense than the original post, i.e. not very helpful for the asker. What does $x\; \lnot R$ mean, anyway?  I've tried to interpret generously to what would make more sense in the two steps following "since".

Comment: What inference rules do you have?  What book are your you using?

Answer (score 1):

$\neg R(c)$ does not contradict $P(c)\to R(c)$.   Recall that a conditional is true if the consequent is true *or* the antecedent is false.   So if you deny the consequent, you assert the antecedent is false.   That is, you use the rule of *modus tollens*.

$\boxed{\begin{array}{l|l:rlr}1 & \forall x~(P(x)\to R(x)) && \text{Premise} \\ 2 & \exists x~(\lnot R(x)\land Q(x)) && \text{Premise} \\\hdashline \quad 3 & \lnot R(c)\wedge Q(c) &2& \text{Assumption (for Existential Elimination)} & \text{Witness } c\\ \quad 4 & \lnot R(c) & 3 & \text{Conjunctive Elimination} \\ \quad 5 & P(c)\to R(c) &1& \text{Universal Elimination} \\ \quad 6 & \color{red}{\lnot P(c)} & 4,5 & \text{Consequent Denial} & \text{(modus tollens)} \\ \quad 7 &  &  &  \\ \quad 8 &  &  &\\\quad 9 &&& \\ \hline 10 & \exists x~(Q(x)\wedge \lnot P(x)) & 2,3{-}9 &\text{Existential Elimination} & \text{Discharge }c  \end{array}}\\\therefore \qquad \forall x~(P(x)\to R(x)), \exists x~(\lnot R(x)\vee Q(x))~\vdash~ \exists x~(Q(x)\wedge \lnot P(x))$

Fill in the remaining steps to complete the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Just a different style:

```
01 ∀x[P(x)→R(x)]       premise
02 ∃x[¬R(x)∧Q(x)]      premise
  03 ¬R(a)∧Q(a)        assumption
  04 ¬R(a)             ∧elim 03
  05 Q(a)              ∧elim 03
    06 P(a)            assumption
    07 P(a)→R(a)       ∀elim 01 a/x
    08 R(a)            →elim 07 06
    09 ⊥               contradiction 08 04
  10 ¬P(a)             ¬intro 06-09
  11 Q(a)∧¬P(a)        ∧intro 05 10
  12 ∃x[Q(x)∧¬P(x)]    ∃intro 11 x/a
13 ∃x[Q(x)∧¬P(x)]      ∃elim 02 03-12
```